# Best method for drawing Bitmaps in android

Tags: android, bitmap, 2d, surfaceview, viewgroup

My app have an input for every 20 millisecond and based on the input I have to draw a Bitmap on the View. I am now using the canvas Draw Bitmap method and found the performance to be bad after 15 minutes, The Android framework started skipping frames because of the overloading. is there any other methods to increase the performance while drawing Bitmaps?

thanks in advance .

Comment: May it helps you: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html

Comment: I would like to know the alternative methods to draw Bitmaps on the view but not to manipulate the Bitmap itslef , but thanks for taking your time and answering

Comment: have u found any method for this purpose?I am having similar issues.